# Are the Thieves Guild's radiant quests broken?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Currently, I'm doing the Thieves' Guild's radiant quests, working to unlock the next set of quests.

> The quests that Delvin give you to "retake" some cities, adding merchants to the Ragged Flagon. These are the prerequisites for becoming the official Guild Master.

So far, I've managed to unlock (and complete) 3 out of 4:

I've done the quests for Whiterun, Windhelm, and Solitude. Only Markarth is missing now.

However, I can't seem to get the last few radiant quests in that area, which I need to unlock the final assignment. I've accepted and cancelled dozens of jobs with both Delvin and Vex (Around 30 - 40 each), but the one city I still need to advance simply never shows up.

Is my luck just *that* bad, or is there something else preventing me from getting any jobs in that area?

Comment: I had exactly the same experience. Just keep trying. I actually saved without the quests then loaded and repeated, not sure if that makes any difference versus cancelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not the only one.
This has been a reported bug, one of many in the quest/radiant questlines.
Depending on the update you've downloaded,which if you have 1.2
you should get 1.3
It's been reported with some succsess that switching to other close by questlines
ie next town,buying your house in the town,even advancing another main storyline
quest say the Bards as an example have shown to help,also the Dark Brotherhood
since they cross paths.

MERRY X-MAS

hope this helped